# filter results based on specific property in realm browser

Tags: realm, realm-browser

How can I filter results based on specific property in `Realm Browser`?
In other words, for example, enter `myproperty=10` in the search box and get the related result.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm Browser doesn't support predicate filtering currently. We track this feature in https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/issues/28.